# How to get the android app activity name in java using adb command

Tags: java, android, adb

Manually launched the application

Code tried:
'''
String cmd = 'adb shell
dumpsys window | find
"microFocus"'
Process res =
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
def output = res.text
print(output)
'''

It is not returning anything.I need to get activity name of the launched application though code.
Please do help! Thanks in Advance

Comment: does the answer below help in figuring out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your requirement is to filter an activity name from the output of `dumpsys windows` command then you probably need to use `grep` instead of `find`.

So to sum up, the right set of commands to use is the following:

```
adb shell dumpsys window | grep -i "microFocus"
```

You should plug it into the `cmd` variable.